# How do I trigger javascript scrollTop() before displaying Body?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a navbar component that only displays after scrolling down more than 650px. My issue is that when I refresh the page the navbar is already being displayed. Everything starts working only after I scroll 1px down the page.

```rb
//application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Coop Interface</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/062b3abfa0.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>

</html>
```

```rb
//navbar.js
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 650) {
        $('.secondary_navbar-coop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.secondary_navbar-coop').fadeOut();
    }

});
```

```rb
//_navbar.scss
.secondary_navbar-coop {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 108px;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #F7FAFB;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10    );      
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;    
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
```

I wish the javascript would be triggered before the body is displayed so I wouldn't see the navbar at refresh and since is the script is placed before the body that's what I would have expected. Any suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the function handler when the dom is ready to determine if the navbar should be displayed.

You must hide the navbar by default with `display: none` to prevent a undesirable flick of the navbar when the document is loading

```
//navbar.js
function scrollHandler() {
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();
  var $navBar = $('.secondary_navbar-coop');

  if (y > 650) {
    if ($navBar.is(':visible') {
      $navBar.css({opacity: 0, display: 'flex'}).animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
    }
  } else {
    $navBar.fadeOut();
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(document).scroll(scrollHandler);
  // scrollHandler will be called when the dom is ready
  scrollHandler();
});

//_navbar.scss
.secondary_navbar-coop {
  display: none;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to work. But the navbar is still being flashed 0.5 second on refresh. Any idea why?

Comment: did you remove the `display: flex` in your css ?

Comment: My bad, I think even thought the scrollHandler is being called, the animation doesn't work. I'll try a few things.

Comment: I made a mistake in the selector, I put `$('.description')` instead of `$('.secondary_navbar-coop')`, I fixed my answer

Comment: Right! Any idea why after it's shown, on every scroll it glitches displaying on and off ?

Comment: yes you only need to trigger the fadeIn animation if the navbar is not displayed, I updated the answer

Comment: Alright I think you meant `if (!$navBar.is(':visible')) {`
Everything works now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call same code on init:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollT op();
        if (y > 650) {
            $('.secondary_navbar-coop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.secondary_navbar-coop').fadeOut();
        }
    }).scroll();
});
```

if your `navbar.js` is included after before closing `</body>` you don't need wrapper `$(function() { });` you only need this is your script is in head.

Comment: the navbar will be probably visible at the very begining of the page render, maybe we should hide the navbar by default

Comment: @OlivierBoissé you're right, for this you can hide it initially, but if page show up scrolled down like when you scroll and refresh, you will see the same flicker but the opposite, it will be hidden and suddenly appear. There is no way to make it work for both.

Comment: exactly, I provided an answer where I am hidding the navbar by default in css

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to detect all scroll events by using an event listener as below.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ 
       var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 650) {
            $('.secondary_navbar-coop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.secondary_navbar-coop').fadeOut();
        }
}, true);
```

Add this in your main JS file.

Comment: I am not quite sure what is the use of this, sorry.